# Alternatives to Importing or Reading Text file with OpenRowSet on Windows 32 in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Good morning my friends:

I used this piece of code in SQL Server to import or read a Text file. I am running a 64bit Machine with Office 2013 Professional (64bit). All works well, that's because I also have the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 64.

```
select *
from openrowset('MSDASQL'
               ,'Driver={Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)}'
               ,'select * from C:\MY_FOLDER\Databases\MY_FILES\mytext_file.txt')
```

The problem is, I started working on another computer which has Office 32, however the Computer is a 64bit machine as-well. Now this code wont work because I cannot install the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 64 with 32 bit office software installed. I need to first uninstall the 32 bit and re-install as 64bit.

I do not have the Office Software to remove/install 32 office.

Are there any other options?

I tried creating a format file but my text file is unpredictable as it is third party and the format always breaks, can't seem to find where the error is. I do not control the quality of this file.

I have also tried most of what is on this page but no luck:

http://bradsruminations.blogspot.in/2011/01/so-you-want-to-read-csv-files-huh.html

This is an update:

I used BULK INSERT: But I am getting double quotes in the data inserted, I am also not getting NULLS, instead double quotes.

**Code:**

```
USE myDatabase;
GO
BULK INSERT my_schema.my_table
   FROM 'C:\MY_FOLDER\Databases\MY_FILES\mytext_file.txt'
   WITH (
      DATAFILETYPE = 'CHAR',
      FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
      ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a',
      FIRSTROW=2, 
      KEEPNULLS
   );
GO
```

Comment: bulk insert? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx

Comment: Thanks: I am getting a ROWTERMINATOR Error. I used this:  ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a', but now I am getting double quotes around the values. See update above, please: